# Ensuring actions can only be performed under certain condition?

Tags: kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin and I'm stuck on how could I tell the program that it can only execute certain functions if a condition is met. Say, you can only increaseTvVolume if TV is turned on, or you can only change the channel if TV is turned on. It's practice from a kotlin course and I'm stuck or just overthinking this. Here's my code: (im trying to achieve that condition in the SmartHome class)

```
 `  

    open class SmartDevice(val name: String, val category: String) {

    var deviceStatus = "online"
        protected set

    open val deviceType = "unknown"

    open fun turnOn() {
        deviceStatus = "on"
    }

    open fun turnOff() {
        deviceStatus = "off"
    }
    
    open fun printDeviceInfo() {
        
        println("Device name: $name, category: $category, type: $deviceType")
    }
    
    }

    class SmartTvDevice(deviceName: String, deviceCategory: String) :
    SmartDevice(name = deviceName, category = deviceCategory) {

    override val deviceType = "Smart TV"

    private var speakerVolume by RangeRegulator(initialValue = 2, minValue = 0, maxValue = 100)

    private var channelNumber by RangeRegulator(initialValue = 1, minValue = 0, maxValue = 200)

    fun increaseSpeakerVolume() {
        speakerVolume++
        println("Speaker volume increased to $speakerVolume.")
    }

    fun nextChannel() {
        channelNumber++
        println("Channel number increased to $channelNumber.")
    }

    override fun turnOn() {
        super.turnOn()
        println(
            "$name is turned on. Speaker volume is set to $speakerVolume and channel number is " +
                "set to $channelNumber."
        )
        }

    override fun turnOff() {
        super.turnOff()
        println("$name turned off")
    }
    
    fun decreaseVolume() {
       speakerVolume--
       println("Speaker volume decreased to $speakerVolume")
       
    }   
    
    fun previousChannel() {
        channelNumber--
        println("Channel number decreased to $channelNumber")
    }
    }

    
    class SmartLightDevice(deviceName: String, deviceCategory: String) :
    SmartDevice(name = deviceName, category = deviceCategory) {

    override val deviceType = "Smart Light"

    private var brightnessLevel by RangeRegulator(initialValue = 0, minValue = 0, maxValue = 100)

    fun increaseBrightness() {
        brightnessLevel++
        println("Brightness increased to $brightnessLevel.")
    }

    override fun turnOn() {
        super.turnOn()
        brightnessLevel = 2
        println("$name turned on. The brightness level is $brightnessLevel.")
    }

    override fun turnOff() {
        super.turnOff()
        brightnessLevel = 0
        println("Smart Light turned off")
    }
    
    fun decreaseBrightness() {
        brightnessLevel--
        println("Brightness decreased to $brightnessLevel")
    }
    
    }

    class SmartHome(
    val smartTvDevice: SmartTvDevice,
    val smartLightDevice: SmartLightDevice
    ) {

    var deviceTurnOnCount = 0
        private set

    fun turnOnTv() {
        deviceTurnOnCount++
        smartTvDevice.turnOn()
    }

    fun turnOffTv() {
        deviceTurnOnCount--
        smartTvDevice.turnOff()
    }

    fun increaseTvVolume(deviceStatus -> "on") {
        smartTvDevice.increaseSpeakerVolume()
    }

    fun changeTvChannelToNext() {
        smartTvDevice.nextChannel()
    }

    fun turnOnLight() {
        deviceTurnOnCount++
        smartLightDevice.turnOn()
    }

    fun turnOffLight() {
        deviceTurnOnCount--
        smartLightDevice.turnOff()
    }

    fun increaseLightBrightness() {
        smartLightDevice.increaseBrightness()
    }

    fun turnOffAllDevices() {
        turnOffTv()
        turnOffLight()
    }
    
   
 
    }

    class RangeRegulator(
    initialValue: Int,
    private val minValue: Int,
    private val maxValue: Int
    ) : ReadWriteProperty<Any?, Int> {

    var fieldData = initialValue

    override fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): Int {
        return fieldData
    }

    override fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: Int) {
        if (value in minValue..maxValue) {
            fieldData = value
        }
    }
    }

    fun main() {
    var smartDevice: SmartDevice = SmartTvDevice("Android TV", "Entertainment")
    smartDevice.turnOn()

    smartDevice = SmartLightDevice("Google Light", "Utility")
    smartDevice.turnOn()
    smartDevice.decreaseBrightness()
    
  
    smartDevice = SmartTvDevice("Android TV", "Entertainment" )
    smartDevice.printDeviceInfo()
    smartDevice.increaseSpeakerVolume()
    smartDevice.increaseSpeakerVolume()
    smartDevice.increaseSpeakerVolume()
    smartDevice.increaseSpeakerVolume()
    smartDevice.increaseSpeakerVolume()
    smartDevice.decreaseVolume()
     
    }

` }
```

IM DEFINITELY OVERTHINKING THIS

The thing is I want all those actions to become unachivable IF deviceStatus is anything but "on"

Comment: Why not simply put an `if` in all such places? Or, if you want to reuse the logic (I'm not sure if it makes sense), create a property delegate, as you already do for keeping some values in a range.

Comment: How could I put an if deviceStatus == on for functions without inherently running them except when you call them? Does that make sense? Or like how could I put a check deviceStatus for "on" before calling the function?

Comment: Ideally you'd do it with types. Instead of a mutable type with `turnOn`/`turnOff` functions, make this class return a new different class when calling `turnOn`, and that new type will have all the functions that are available on a device that is on.

Comment: Why do you need to check the status before calling the function and not inside it? Do you mean to separate the logic of filtering input events (checking the status) and actually handling these events?

Comment: What I want is for the function to ONLY be executable if deviceStatus is on, I'm new to this so I'm just brainstorming ways to do that.

Comment: I have a function turnOn that sets deviceStatus to on and a turnOff function that sets it to off

Comment: What is your expected behavior if I write a code like this: `smartDevice.turnOff(); smartDevice.increaseSpeakerVolume()`?

Comment: Since you called the turnOff function on smartDevice, I'd want it to print a message "device is turned off" instead of executing the increaseSpeakerVolume() method because deviceStatus doesnt meet the criteria of being "on"

Comment: So how putting an `if` inside the `increaseSpeakerVolume()` is different than what you need? Yeah, I know, you want this function to not be called at all, but why? What's the difference between not calling a function and calling a function which returns doing nothing?

Comment: You are not stupid, maybe a little lost :-) If you try to put this check in `SmartHome`, then please note smart home doesn't know the status of devices, it only delegated to them. `SmartTvDevice` knows if it is currently turned on or off, so this is where you could/should put your checks.

Comment: Calling an if deviceStatus == "on" inside the functions results in unresolved reference? Either im stupid or m doing something wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following these steps:

Create the function `isDeviceOn()` returning a `Boolean` value

```
open fun isDeviceOn() : Boolean {
    return this.deviceStatus == "online" || this.deviceStatus == "on"
}
```

With this function you check if `deviceStatus` is equal to `"online"` or `"on"`. If one of these criteria is met, the function return `true`, if not returns `false`.

If you need to check if the device is on **from inside the class** you can directly use

```
if (this.isDeviceOn()) {
    // Device is on
} else {
    // Device is off
}
```

If you have an **instance of SmartDevice** you can use

```
val device = SmartDevice(...)
if (device.isDeviceOn()) {
     // Device is on
} else {
     // Device is off
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I said I was overthinking this. I did what I wanted with a simple if statement:

```
` fun increaseSpeakerVolume() {
            if (deviceStatus == "on") {
            speakerVolume++
            println("Speaker volume increased to $speakerVolume.")
            }
        }`
```

And I did it for each function. When I run it with this:

```
`smartDevice.turnOff(); smartDevice.increaseSpeakerVolume()`
```

I get:

Android TV turned off

When I run with:

```
smartDevice.turnOn(); smartDevice.increaseSpeakerVolume()
```

I get:

Android TV is turned on. Speaker volume is set to 1 and channel number is set to 1.
Speaker volume increased to 2.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! Just took me two hours for a few lines of code

Comment: This approach could work, but creating a function to check if the device is on would be the best practice since you can use it everywhere you need.

Comment: I see! I can do that too thanks!